# Как отобразить таблицу mysql в админке django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

При работе с django 3 я использую mysql.

У меня есть таблица mysql, данные в ней должны добавляться в админке. Но мне не удается подключить таблицу в админку.

Насколько я понял, нужно обявить базу в моделях а потом зарегистрировать в файле admin. Но я не смог найти ни одного примера как это делают именно с MYSQL.

Подскажите как правильно связать таблицу Mysql с админкой, и можно ли вообще.

Comment: Верно вы не нашли, ибо вывод таблица в mysql ничем не отличается от вывода таблицы любой другой бд в джанго. Вы думаете в верном направлении про модели. Изучите типы полей в моделях и их sql соответствия, и все станет на свои места

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку.
Я создал в модели класс с именем нужной таблицы. В классе прописал все нужные поля в соответствии с типом полей в mysql.

Далее в базе данных, к текущей таблице дописал в название префикс с именем приложения в django. Имя таблицы выглядело следующим образом: nameApp_nameClass. Где nameApp - имя приложения в джанго. nameClass - имя класса в модели в котором объявили все поля.

И это действительно сработало

Для примера скидываю свой класс и имя таблицы.

Имя таблицы - training_item. 
Имя Django приложения - training.

Класс в model.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    reps = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    sets = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    rest_time = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    training = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

def __str__(self):
    return self.training, '>>', self.exercise
```

Регистрация в admin.py

```
admin.site.register(List)
```